# Angular (Javascript) how to use map and filter for an Observable array to filter for datetime and return array of new similar objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, observable

I am getting an array of data from a http get request. This Data is as follows:
[image]

as you can see, its an array of 4 similar documents, each doc has

```
{name:"...", series: [{name:"...",value:"..."},...]}
```

as its structure.
Now, I would like to create a new array based on this array, where I filter each top-level document inside the array for its series name (~datetime) field, based on some datetime parameter that I pass from a function (to be precise, from a datetimepicker).

```
filterDatetime(start, end, array) {
    this.actualData = array.map(el => el.series)
      .filter(dok => {new Date(dok.name) > new Date(start) && new Date(dok.name) < new Date(end)})
    }
```

I tried to apply the above function to filter the series array for the start and end datetime, to return me a similar document structure as in the pictures, just with the new filtered series array... but somehow this does not work.

And furthermore, I am using observables. I save my returned observable data inside a variable, this variable should be present already in the chart when the page has loaded, therefore, if you use datetimepicker to choose a date range, the data at the variable should normally already be present.

However, I am not sure how it will behave exactly if it comes from an observable (also if its already present). 
So maybe I have to be careful to return not an empty array or so (I am still new to observables, so don't know if this works like that).

Edit: I could send a new http request to the database and filter directly on the data, but I would like to learn those map / filter / reduce etc. methods to do the manipulation directly with the present data, as I think this will be more convenient in later development stages.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make the filtering where you make now the http GET request.

```
    private theSubject = new BehaviorSubject<>();
    this.data =     this.httpGetRequest()
                        .pipe(
                                filter(dok => {new Date(dok.name) > new Date(start) && new Date(dok.name) < new Date(end)}),
                                toArray()
                            )
                        .subscribe((dok: any) =>
                                    this.theSubject.next(dok),
                            );
```